# Can working family business come across as lack of competitiveness?

Tags: interviewing, family-business

If an interviewer by any chance discovered my previous job was owned by my family, would this come across as a lack of competitiveness, as in having failed to find a job externally?

Comment: Dark Cygnus laid it out well.  If you're concerned about it, perhaps don't speak to it being a family business on your resume/CV.  Then before the interview, take some time to consider how you will tell your story around it so you're ready to discuss it if it does come up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> would this come across as a lack of competitiveness, as in having failed to find a job externally?

This will depend on that interviewer and how *they* will take it.

However, this does not necessarily mean or denote lack of competitiveness.

You competitiveness and skill is usually gauged by looking at other aspects on a CV, like what kind of *tasks and responsibilities* you had, what *tools or resources* do you know and use, etc., as those are factors that give hints on how someone may perform in my company if I were to hire them.

Employment time and distribution is also useful to analyze, as having several jobs with short time in each in the past may raise some suspicions as if the candidate has had a stable job record.

If I see a candidate that is fit and knowledgeable for the role I seek, and performs well in the interview process I would strongly consider them for the job regardless if they previously worked in a family business.

Comment: It also depends a bit on how "OP" sells the job in the interview. Their reasons for working in the family business can tell a lot about the candidate's values and priorities.